# Run Pig scripts in Parallel on Amazon AWS

Tags: apache-pig, oozie, amazon-emr

We currently run all our Pig jobs sequentially on Amazon EMR, so we launch a cluster and then add all our Pig jobs as a step to the cluster 1 by 1.
While this works, I was wondering if there is something that can allow you to run those Pig jobs in parallel.

Ideally I would like to do the following:
Launch a cluster (let's say c3.xlarge) and then throw 15 pig jobs at it.
Those jobs would then run in parallel as best as they can (eg: 3 at the same time) and when 1 is done, another one gets executed.

Any help would be appreciated if something like this exist and how we could use it. I read something about Oozie but I am not sure if this would suit our needs.

Answer (score 1):

EMR steps cannot be made to run in parallel. However like you mentioned, use oozie to orchestrate your pig script execution using fork and join actions to run in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it's possible if you manually reconfigure your EMR cluster to use Fair scheduler and submit tasks via shell. Or probably you could go the qay with Oozie. But generally it's not like from the box.

Answer (score 1):

Oozie can help you run the pig scripts in parallel. For scheduling parallel execution of the pig scripts you can use the Fork-Join control nodes. For example [Fork and Join Control Nodes](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.1.5_Fork_and_Join_Control_Nodes).

The only thing is, it will start the execution of all the forked scripts in parallel, does not provide you to control a fixed parallelism. You need to manage it yourself in oozie workflow application definition. For [Pig action](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.3_Pig_Action) check the doc.

The two map-reduce jobs will execute in parallel. You can use a combination of jobs here like Pig, Hive, Map-Reduce etc.

```
<workflow-app name="sample-wf" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
    ...
    <fork name="forking">
        <path start="firstparalleljob"/>
        <path start="secondparalleljob"/>
    </fork>
    <action name="firstparallejob">
        <map-reduce>
            <job-tracker>foo:8021</job-tracker>
            <name-node>bar:8020</name-node>
            <job-xml>job1.xml</job-xml>
        </map-reduce>
        <ok to="joining"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <action name="secondparalleljob">
        <map-reduce>
            <job-tracker>foo:8021</job-tracker>
            <name-node>bar:8020</name-node>
            <job-xml>job2.xml</job-xml>
        </map-reduce>
        <ok to="joining"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <join name="joining" to="nextaction"/>
    ...
</workflow-app>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, already had a look at Oozie but I am not sure if fits my needs. Cause I don't think Oozie takes the available resources into account (by default)

Comment: Oozie does not take the resource availability into account. It submits the jobs to Yarn/MR framework and depends on it. Thanks.